# Associate java with websocket

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, tomcat9, java-websocket

I have several processes or nodes called A, B and C, which speak between them via sockets. I want to print their state as they speak via a websocket.

To that end, I created a class named `WebSocket` with the necesary `@ApplicationScoped`, `@ServerEndpoint("/status")`, `@OnOpen`, `@OnMessage`, `@OnClose` and `@OnError` tags. Each tag has its corresponding function. I also created a TomCat server.

The problem is I can't manage to get my processes to speak to the TomCat server and vice versa through the `WebSocket` class.

Executing my tomcat server, runs an instance of `WebSocket` where the value of Node is `null` so making a get to fetch the node's status and printing it is not viable.

The other way around, when executing my nodes, each creates a `WebSocket` but it's unable to comunicate with Tomcat.

End result is my three nodes running with three instances of `WebSocket` that can't talk to tomcat while tomcat is running with it's own `WebSocket` instance that can't fetch the node's status.

Could someone please clarify:

- Which way is the communication meant to be? Are websockets designed to fetch info or to just wait until it is sent to him.
- How to solve my issue, ideally by creating first the nodes (each with its own `WebSocket`) and the tomcat server just waiting to be sent info.
- To display the screen I made a small .html file (http://localhost:63343/test/web/index.html) but tomcat has one that opens up when runned (http://localhost:8080/test_war_exploded/). If I manage to send messages correctly from the nodes to the tomcat server, which of these two website will be getting the messages? AKA which one is valid?

EDIT:

I just tested executing the Tomcat server and with it, several sockets. Each socket executes a new `WebSocket` and I can then execute a different node based on a parameter given to the `WebSocket`.

This is not an option. It might work but in my case all nodes must be separate programs, and doing this means they are all a same program, but simply under different threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The client needs it's own class to communicate with the server, which is not there. `WebSocket` class is used by the Tomcat server and the client shouldn't use it, needs a new one.

Follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2R_Iyga88E) for a good example.

In my case it made me understand my design mistake. I get a `Could not find an implementation class` exception on the `ContainerProvider`, but that's another story.